# How to enumerate PropertySheet shell extension associated with extension

Tags: winapi, shell-extensions

I want to fill a list with the PropertySheet shell extensions associated with a file extension. I found the [`SHGetAssocKeys()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and it looks like it allows me to enumerate all HKEYs associated with the file extension and I can read all `shellex\PropertySheetHandlers` values. But this function is only available on Windows 8. What about XP, Vista and 7? Is there any official way?

**UPDATE**

I want to get list of HKEY like this:

- `HKCR\MyProgID\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers`
- `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.MyExt\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers`
- `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\MyPercivedType\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers`
- `HKCR\*\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers`
- `HKCR\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers`

Comment: `IQueryAssociations` has been around since Win2000, it is only `SHGetAssocKeys()` that was added in Win8.  Worse case, you can simply use `RegOpenKeyEx()`, `RegEnumKey()` and `RegQueryValueEx()` to enumerate/read the property sheet registrations directly. The layout of the relevant Registry keys is documented: [How to Register and Implement a Property Sheet Handler for a File Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127448.aspx)

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: I know about IQueryAssociations. But I don`t know how to use IQueryAssociations to enumerate IPropertyStore handlers. I can use RegXXX function but I am looking for official way.

Comment: Despite what MSDN says, `SHGetAssocKeys()` was actually introduced in Vista, exported from SHELL32.DLL at ordinal 777. It was exported by name and documented in Win8. See this article, which has some details about the inner workings of `SHGetAssocKeys()`: http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/shell32/api/assocutil/getkeys.htm. Depending on what you want to use the property sheets for, also have a look at `AssocGetPropListForExt()`: http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/shell32/api/assocutil/getproplistforext.htm

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: I already read all related articles from geoffchappell.com before I post my question and did not find solution. Not sure about Vista but shell32.dll in Windows 7 does not contain exported function with ordinal 777.

Comment: Yes, Shell32.dll does have an exported function at ordinal 777 on Win7, and it has a function signature consistent with `SHGetAssocKeys()`. I checked that before I posted my last comment. And geoffchappell.com would not have documented it as such if it did not work.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: You are right. It looks like a bug in the tool I used for exam shell32.dll export. The function at ordinal 777 really exists. And it fully solves my problem on Vista and 7. Do you have any idea about Windows XP?

Comment: For XP, you are likely to have to resort to the `Reg...()` functions, since all of the interfaces that `SHGetAssocKeys()` uses internally, as documented by geoffchappell.com, were added in Vista.